# What is the difference between data types aside from length in memory?

Tags: c++, disassembly, machine-code

I've been trying to wrap my head around how C/C++ code is represented in machine code and I'm having trouble understanding what data types actually are apart from a designation of memory length.

Comment: They also define what operations are available for the values in memory, as well as how they are performed.

Comment: C/C++ doesn‘t exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types also are associated with;

- a set of values that all variables of that type can represent;
- the layout in memory of that type (e.g. the meaning, if any, attached to each bit or byte that represents a variable),
- the set of operations that can act on a variable;
- the behaviour of those operations.

Types are not necessarily represented directly in machine code.  A compiler emits a set of instructions and data (in a way that varies between target platforms) that manipulate memory and machine registers.   The type of each variable, in C source, gives information to the compiler about what memory to allocate for it, and the compiler makes decisions for mapping between expressions (in C statements) and usage of registers and machine instructions to give the required effects.

Comment: Could you add examples with types of same length that have different behavior when used interchangeably in code and explain what happens to cause the different behavior?

Comment: `unsigned` and `int` are (on any specified target machine) the same size, but represent a different set of values (an `unsigned` cannot represent negative values, an `int` does).  Overflowing an `unsigned` uses modulo arithmetic (e.g. a result of `-1` is wrapped around to become the maximum value an `unsigned` can represent on that target machine) while overflowing an `int` gives undefined behaviour (and results of overflowing an `int` DO vary between compilers, even between two compilers that have `int` the same size).    That's just the way the standard specifies them.